# Building Iroha in Docker with cmake

Tags: docker, cmake, hyperledger-iroha

I try to build Iroha Hyperledger using Doker. after I clone the image and try to execute the build with CMake

```
cmake -H. -Bbuild -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/dependencies/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -G "Ninja"
```

I got this error:

```
Could not find toolchain file:
  /opt/dependencies/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (PROJECT)
```

**I use CMake 3.16**

Any help

Comment: Error message "could not find toolchain file" seems to be self-explanatory: CMake cannot find the file which you specify with `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands to do (as @kyb said) and according to [instruction](https://iroha.readthedocs.io/en/main/build/index.html#linux-pre):

1. Installing dependencies:

```
apt-get update; \
apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
build-essential ninja-build \
git ca-certificates tar curl unzip cmake
```

2. Clonning iroha:

```
git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha.git
```

3. Building dependencies:

```
iroha/vcpkg/build_iroha_deps.sh
vcpkg/vcpkg integrate install
```

As a result You will see command like:

```
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

4. Finally You need to add the command to the CMake command (as You provided):

```
cmake -H. -Bbuild -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/dependencies/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -G "Ninja"
```

5. Last step would be run ninja:

```
cmake --build . --target irohad -- -j<number of threads>
```

6. Optionally You can install the binaries:

```
cmake --install . --target irohad
```

Answer (score 2):

You should build vcpkg and install vcpkg packages before building iroha. Please refer [the docs](https://iroha.readthedocs.io/en/main/build/index.html#linux-pre).